# Opening multiple files both vertically and horizontally from the command line

Tags: command-line, split

I'm trying to open vim in a format like this, from the command line.

```
|----------------|
|         |  2   |
|         |------|
|    1    |  3   |
|         |------|
|         |  4   |
|----------------|
```

If this was in Vim, I could use `:vsp :sp :sp :sp`. I know that I could split them all vertically or horizontally with `-o` and `-O`, but trying to use both opens them all with the first flag mentioned.

Is there a way I could open vim this way?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I marked your question as a duplicate since the other question seems to match this one very closely and it has two good answers that apply in your case too. Please comment if you feel that it doesn't fully address your question. Cheers!

Comment: BTW, no need to delete the question... Duplicates can be useful (if properly marked as such) in that they increase the chance someone will find what they're looking for.

Comment: For future reference, I used ```vim -c "rightb vsplit file2.txt|split file4.txt|split file3.txt" file1.txt```